# Ruby on Rails Gitorious: uninitialized constant Rails::Plugin::OpenID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gitorious

I am trying to setup gitorious yousource branch, I've followed partly this article: http://www.lacerta.be/d7/content/gitorious-ubuntu-natty

Everything was installed but I get this error:

```
Error message:
   uninitialized constant Rails::Plugin::OpenID
Exception class:
   NameError
Application root:
   /var/www/gitorious
```

My Gemfile has gem "ruby-openid", :require => 'openid' but doesn't work anyway.

Anyone know how could i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not loading "ruby-openid" before the OpenID is called in Rails::Plugin namespace.